# measuring the height of a space

Tags: measurement

I used Polycam to do some 3D scans of a tunnel, a while ago, and I'd like to be able to determine the height of the tunnel at various places in my scans.

I can use the Measure tool to draw a line and Blender will then tell me the height of the line I've drawn but what I'd like to be able to do is to make sure one end of the line is on the bottom of the tunnel and the other end of the line is on the top of the tunnel. Unfortunately, it's not clear to me how to do this, short of eyeballing it.

Ideally the line would be straight up too as opposed to being at an angle. In real life, this would be facilitated by the use of a level.

Here's a picture of my scan:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I usually just create a bunch of boxes by extruding a plane. You can see the height of each box in the properties panel. Can you tell us more about the problems you are facing and what you can't achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually add another mesh made of simple edges and enable the "edge lenght" overlay. Then I create edges perpedicular to the ground by extruding only on Z amd snapping to the pieces of the scanned mesh.

[image]

Another way is to use some other object as a reference and look at its Z size on the properties panel.

[image]